# What is wrong with this expressions? =CountRows(ReportItems!Textbox58.Value = "Intervene"). I want to count each row which says Intervene

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

What is wrong with this expression? `=CountRows(ReportItems!Textbox58.Value = "Intervene")`

I want to count each row which says Intervene.

Comment: If you want to count the number of rows that value a value in a dataset, you want to use `COUNT` against the Field in the dataset; not a text box. `COUNTROWS` just tells you how many rows are in the specified scope.

Comment: Side note, if you *are* using SSRS 2008 I strongly recommend you get your upgrade path sorted. SQL Server 2008 and Visual Studio 2008 have long been completely unsupported.

Answer (score 2):

As Larnu has commented, you cannot use CountRows against the ReportItems collection.

Probably what you need to do is

Look at the expression in Textbox58 and see where it gets it's data from. In this exmaple let's say it comes from Fields!myFieldName.Value.

Now we need to count the rows where Fields!myFieldName.Value = "Intervene" but rather than using count, we can convert these matches to return `1` or `0` where the field is not "Intervene"

So the expression would look something like this

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!myFieldName.Value = "Intervene", 1, 0))
```

This will sum the rows withing the current scope, so if this is contained in a row group for example, then it will only sum those rows in that row group.

If you need to count based on a a different scope (e.g. the entire dataset) then you can specify that in the `SUM()` function like this

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!myFieldName.Value = "Intervene", 1, 0), "DataSet1")
```

Here we are summing across the entire dataset where the dataset name is `DataSet1`

---

Update based on OP comment

As your expression is

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Actual_Duration.Value >= 10, "Intervene", "No Intervention Needed"))
```

What we actually need to count is instances where `Actual_Duration` is >= 10.

So the final expression should be

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Actual_Duration.Value >= 10, 1, 0))
```

Comment: Thanks Alan, I'm hoping you can give me some additional help to convert my expressions in to an actual field. I have currently got the following: =SUM(IIF(Fields!Actual_Duration.Value >= 10, "Intervene", "No Intervention Needed")) but the expression isn't working to become a field. Do you know why?