# How to convert my expressions in to an actual field without showing an error? =SUM(IIF(Fields!Actual_Duration.Value >= 10, "Intervene", "Leave"))

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

How to convert my expressions in to an actual field without showing an error? I am trying to create the below into a field so I can use an expression which will count the "Intervenes"

=SUM(IIF(Fields!Actual_Duration.Value >= 10, "Intervene", "Leave"))

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is wrong with this expressions? =CountRows(ReportItems!Textbox58.Value = "Intervene"). I want to count each row which says Intervene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70710917/what-is-wrong-with-this-expressions-countrowsreportitemstextbox58-value-i)

Comment: this is a follow up question on a question that has already been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70710917/what-is-wrong-with-this-expressions-countrowsreportitemstextbox58-value-i/70711253?noredirect=1#comment125005964_70711253

Answer (score 0):

If your Intervene and Leave are fields in your dataset, you would use the field values liek you did with Actual_Duration.

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Actual_Duration.Value >= 10, Fields!Intervene.Value, Fields!Leave.Value))
```

The will add the SUM the Intervene values when the Actual Duration is >= 10 along with the Leaves values when Actual Duration is < 10.